# Go atomic store followed by atomic load is behaving erratically across routines

Tags: go, atomic

I am trying to store a map as unsafe. Pointer and trying to retrieve it later. Below is the code snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

type MapHolder struct {
    ptr unsafe.Pointer
}

func (m MapHolder) Set(myMap map[string]int64) {
    atomic.StorePointer(&m.ptr, unsafe.Pointer(&myMap))
    fmt.Printf("The pointer value is: %v\n", atomic.LoadPointer(&m.ptr))
}

func (m MapHolder) Get() map[string]int64 {
    ptr := atomic.LoadPointer(&m.ptr)
    if ptr == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Why is this pointer value nil?")
        return nil
    } else {
        return *(*map[string]int64)(ptr)
    }
}

func main() {
    var m MapHolder
    test := make(map[string]int64)
    test["hello"] = 1
    m.Set(test)
    m.Get()

}
```

When `Set()`, executes, it prints the contents of `m.ptr` correctly. However, when we do a `Get()`, it returns nil. This looks totally un-expected to me. I am using go 1.11.6

The output of the above program is:

```
The pointer loaded is: 0x40c130
```

Why is this pointer value nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `Set` method has a value receiver,  the receiver value and any changes to the value are discarded when the method returns. Fix the problem by using pointer receivers.

```
func (m *MapHolder) Set(myMap map[string]int64) { ... }
func (m *MapHolder) Get() map[string]int64 { ... }
```

The `Get` method must also use a pointer receiver to prevent a data race on the copy of the receiver argument.

The `Set` method stores the address of argument `myMap`, not the address of `m` in `main`.  This may or may not be a problem depending on how the application uses `MapHolder`.